# After screen lock, open windows jump to other monitor

Tags: 22.04, .desktop

(regular Ubuntu 22.04 desktop - fully updated)

After my screen locks, I always have some windows moving from one monitor to another. If I had 2 similar size monitors, it wouldn't bother me that much, but windows moving from my 4K screen to the HD screen can be really annoying.
From a security POV, I do not wish to turn off my automatic screen lock.

Is there any setting I can turn on (or off?) that preserves the location of my open windows?

Comment: this is most likely a bug. plesase report to Canonical. meanwhile  as a workaround minimize whenever you go to the lock screen minimize the open windows.

Comment: Some bug reports that may be related: [1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1927948), [2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1778983), [3](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2092), [4](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2131)